# Can't export SVG properly

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, svg, export, web-safe

I want to export a file from Adobe Illustrator but it's kinda messing it up. I've no idea why.

In case you don't see the problem instantly: The *shadow* (3D Extrude & Bevel effect) of the gray line gets cut at multiple positions.

My export Settings: I've fiddled with a lot of different settings around but couldn't get it any better.

[image: export setting svg from Adobe Illustrator]

---

Original vector from Adobe Illustrator:

[image: original vector illustration]

Exported SVG, as seen in any common browser:

[image: result of svg file exported from Illustrator]

3D Extrude & Bevel effect

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to expand your object. It's located under **Object** in the main menu. After that use the **Select- same - fill color**, and the pathfinder palette to combine the colors into one single object. Play around and it will become intuitive. good luck.